# Paste Excel Range to PowerPoint Slide in 2016 with Windows 10

Tags: vba, powerpoint, excel-2016

I want to copy and paste an Excel Range into a PowerPoint slide. The range has conditional formatting, number formats and border formats. Here is what I have:

```
mwksTables.Range("T_Table").Copy  
mobjPowerPointSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial 0
```

This code works but doesn't paste keeping the original formatting. If I change the code to the following:

```
mobjPowerPointSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial 2
```

it prints correctly but magnifies it so as to show only half of the data in the object (weird). It's like it zooms the range after copying but before pasting.

I have tried this:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
```

But this only works for Office 2010.

Can someone help? How can I paste a table into PowerPoint 2016 and make it look identical to the range in Excel 2016? Thanks!

Comment: I assume the other possible formats - e.g. JPG/bitmap/PNG, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/pppastedatatype-enumeration-powerpoint) - have the same "zoom" error?

Comment: @BigBen I've tried every enum and they all either have the zoom problem, or wrong format, or right format but no color format from the conditional formatting in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting it as an OLE object...

```
oSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial 10 'ppPasteOLEObject
```

Then you will also be able to either edit the worksheet object in PowerPoint or open it in Excel.